# where to make con variable global if i am including con from anathor file

Tags: php

I have included connection resource file in anathor php . I am making a small website.But when i use $run_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);
Error comes that mysqli_query want paramenter 1 to be mysqli , null given

i tried to put global $con in place of use and near con = mysqli_connect
but none works

This is includes/db.php

```
   <?php 
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce",3307);
 ?>
```

IN Insert product page including at top

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<? php
include("includes/db.php");
?>

<select name="product_cat">
<option>Select a Category</option>
<?php
global $con;
$get_cats = "select * from categories";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);
                    while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
 $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
$cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
echo " <option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>  ";
}
?>

</select>
```

here $con is coming null .

i expect connection to come here, but null comes , there some problem with con scope. how to deal it.

Comment: You shouldn't need `global $con;` at all.  The file is included above, so the variable is declared already.  If it still fails when you remove that then it sounds like something else is failing, such as the `include` itself not finding the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Your includes/db.php file**

In the way you are using $con in your example, $con is within the scope of the rest of the code. So something else might be going on.

You should be testing what $conn is. i.e check that the connection was successful before proceeding.

Something like...

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce",3307);
if (!$con)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

**It could be failing on the include and not setting $conn**

What is the location of the file in your sample code?

If it is a case of the include failing, it matters where it is, relative to your include path/filename.

**Enable Error Reporting**

Add these two lines somewhere where it's always going to be run. This will ensure you will see any errors. There are other ways to do this but I will leave that for you to look into.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

*So assuming your db.php is always being included, you could have*

```
<?php 
// These Two Lines ONLY for Debugging.
// Remove when using in production.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce",3307);
if (!$con)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

**Scope of $con**

In your sample code $con is within the same scope, so it will be seen if its being set correctly.

In the case of functions, it won't be, so you would then declare $con as global within the function OR you could pass it in as a parameter. The choice is yours.

**Update.**

I have tested your code and *"it works for me"* so you've picked the wrong reason for why your code is not working. It's definitely not a scoping issue, so try the other suggestions and see if that leads you to success.

**Are you sure your connection/database details are correct?**

Are you sure your connection details are correct? It could be as simple as that. The added checks in your db.php will immediately tell you what the reason is.

Comment: @aakashsharma from your comment above, am I correct in saying you got it working? So what was the fix?